# Lambda expression causes "first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, collections, lambda

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in .dll. I cannot figure out why all.FindAll(...) throws this exception every time. Is the reason because the lambda expression is not short circuiting the AND OR conditions which is causing the Name, BillingCity, and or BillingStreet to cause this? Also I'm open to a better approach (like a working one =)) to my current solution.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> AutoCompleteSearch(string term)
    {
        // Filter accounts
        List<Account> all = await GetAccounts();
        List<Account> filtered = new List<Account>();

        filtered = all.FindAll(e => 
            ((e.Name != null) && e.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())) ||
            ((e.BillingCity != null) && e.BillingCity.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())) ||
            ((e.BillingStreet != null) && e.BillingState.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())));

        return Json(filtered, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: `(e.BillingStreet != null) && e.BillingState`. You're checking for null on the wrong property.

Comment: wow! ty... sorry for wasting your time and ty!

Comment: @crush you should respond with this as the answer since you were first to resolve this. That way I can give points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a simple typo, probably from intellisense autocompletion.

On this line:

```
((e.BillingStreet != null) && e.BillingState.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())));
```

You check `BillingStreet` for `null`, but then attempt to access `BillingState` property. One of these is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You never null check e.BillingState. Add

```
&& e.BillingState
```

before

```
&& e.BillingState.ToLower()
```

Comment: Thank you @MBeatty I would have marked this as the answer, but crush answered this first in a comment. Thank you again.